# Check if a checkbox is checked and apply style to parent element with jquery

Tags: jquery, css, checkbox

I have a list with checkboxes like this:

```
<ul class="cate_select_ul">
    <li>
        <!-- outer checkbox A -->
        <label><input value="251" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]">Automobiles &amp; Transport</label>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>
                <!-- inner checkbox A -->
                <label><input value="252" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]">Car Parts</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <!-- outer checkbox B -->
        <label><input value="251" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]">Automobiles &amp; Transport</label>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>
                <!-- inner checkbox B -->
                <label><input value="252" type="checkbox" name="post_category[]">Car Parts</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I want to check if the inner checkbox is checked or not. If so I want to change the style of the label around the parent outer checkbox.
 I tried this but it won't work properly:

```
if($('ul.children input[name="post_category[]"]:checked').length > 0){
$("this").parent().parent().parent().parent().children("label").css({"color":"red"});
}
```

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Where did you put your snippet in? You should make sure what you can get from $(this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example isn't working because `$("this")` attempts to select an element with a tag type of `<this>`. Since that element doesn't exist, nothing is selected.

Normally, `$("this")` should be `$(this)` (since [`this` is a keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) and not a string), however in your case, it doesn't refer to the element that you think it does because it doesn't look like there is any scope. In your case, the variable `this` probably refers to the `window` object; you can always check with `console.log(this)`.

---

As for a solution, you could iterate over the elements using the [`.each()` method](https://api.jquery.com/each/) in order for `this` to refer to the current checked `input` element. You also don't need to chain the `.parent()` method four times since you can use the [`.closest()` method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) in order to select the specified closest ancestor:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/yktm32ph/)

```
$('ul.children input[name="post_category[]"]:checked').each(function() {
  $(this).closest('.children').prev('label').css('color', '#f00');
});
```

---

Of course you don't actually need to use `.each()` method since you can just select the elements directly.

In the line below, the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) is used in order to select `ul.children` elements that have checked `input[name="post_category[]"]` descendant elements. From there, the previous `label` element is selected and the corresponding CSS is changed:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/f45ta2rk/)

```
$('ul.children:has(input[name="post_category[]"]:checked)').prev('label').css('color', '#f00');
```

---

As a side note, if you want to put this in a `change` event listener, it would look something like this:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/m03x5uye/)

```
$('ul.children input[name="post_category[]"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('.children').prev('label').toggleClass('selected', this.checked);
});
```

Comment: Not only is this a correct answer. I was able to learn so much! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Dear Josh, when I tried to change "has" by "not" to color just the labels of the children checkbox lists who are empty, all the outer labels became red. =S Any hints?

Comment: @mesqueeb Then I'm pretty sure you want to wrap `:not()` around `:has()` like `$('ul.children:not(:has(...))')`. So it would be `$('ul.children:not(:has(input[name="post_category[]"]:checked))').prev('label').css('color', '#f00');` -> [updated example](https://jsfiddle.net/j7g2L02t/).

Comment: Thanks Josh!
I got exactly what I needed with a combination of 3 of your examples:
https://jsfiddle.net/nqcabpzo/
Would you deem this code good to your standards? ^^

Comment: @mesqueeb Yeah; that looks fine.

Comment: I tried to add the functionality to check the parent checkbox, but I can't seem to make it work... You do you any ideas? https://jsfiddle.net/nqcabpzo/2/

Comment: @mesqueeb Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/3pt8cqxp/)? If not, take a look at [this simplified example](https://jsfiddle.net/3pqb1pjb/).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103452/discussion-between-mesqueeb-and-josh-crozier).